# Location address on tap in OpenStreetMap Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am using the dispatchTouchEvent() method to tap the map. When I tap on anywhere on the layout it shows the lat & long, but I want it to only show when I tap on the map area. I don't know what wrong with this code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int actionType = ev.getAction();
    switch (actionType) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        proj = mapView.getProjection();
        loc = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) ev.getX(), (int) ev.getY());
        String longitude = Double
                .toString(((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000);
        String latitude = Double
                .toString(((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude: "
                + longitude + " Latitude: " + latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Here is an image of the layout:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have solved this. Here you can see he solution.

```
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {

        Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
        p = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
         proj = mapView.getProjection();
         loc = (GeoPoint) proj.fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
         String longitude = Double
         .toString(((double) loc.getLongitudeE6()) / 1000000);
         String latitude = Double
         .toString(((double) loc.getLatitudeE6()) / 1000000);
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "Longitude: "
         + longitude + " Latitude: " + latitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
        return true;
    }
```